# Represent vector subspace with an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following problem:

> Let $S := \{(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1), (1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1),  (2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)\}$.We shall denote $\alpha_i$ to the $i$th element of $S$.

> Let $W_1 = \{(x_1, ..., x_6) : x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0, x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 0 \}, 
>         W_2 = \text{span(S)}$.

> Give a base, a dimension and an equation for $W_1 \cap W_2$

I was able to find a basis and, therefore, a dimension. However, I have trouble understanding what is being ment by "give an equation of $W_1 \cap W_2$".

I proceeded by noting that, for coefficients $x, y, z, w \in \mathbb{R}$, any $v \in W_2$ is of the general form

\begin{align*}
    v = \begin{bmatrix}x + y +z + 2w \\
    -x + w \\ 
    x + 2y - z \\
    -x + y - z \\
    x\\
    -x + z\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Then any $v$ such that $v \in (W_2 \cap W_1)$ must be of such general form and also satisfy the system

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 0 \\
        x_4 + x_5 + x_6 &= 0
    \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}
        x + 3y +3w &= 0 \\
        -x + y &= 0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Solving the system gives the solution space

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{X} = \left( -\frac{3}{4}w,  -\frac{3}{4}w, z, w\right)
\end{equation*}

Then

\begin{equation*}
    W_1 \cap W_2 = \left\{-\frac{3}{4}w \alpha_1  -\frac{3}{4}w \alpha_2 + z\alpha_3 + w\alpha_4 \mid w, z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
\end{equation*}

This readily implies that $S$ is a basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$, and that $W_1 \cap W_2$ is four-dimensional. But once more, how am I to represent this subspace as an equation?

Comment: If your solution space for $v$ in $W_1\cap W_2$ is the set of all $(-(3/4)w,-(3/4)w,z,w)=(-3/4,-3/4,0,1)w+(0,0,1,0)z$, that's two-dimensional, not four.

Comment: $(-\frac{3}{4}w, -\frac{3}{4}w, z, w)$ are the coefficients that must appear in the linear combination of the four-dimensional basis $S = \{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_4 \}$ so as to ensure the spanned vectors are both in $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: Am I confusing something?

Comment: I don't know what your 4-dimensional basis is. You splash those alphas onto the page without any introduction or hint of their meaning. What exactly do you mean by $\alpha_1$?

Comment: The meaning was always clear.  "We shall denote $\alpha_i$ to the $i$th element of $S$". I didn't splash them onto anything haha. It's literally the second sentence in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found$$W_1 \cap W_2 = \left\{\left.w\left(-\frac34\alpha_1-\frac34\alpha_2+\alpha_4\right) + z\alpha_3\,\right|\,w, z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
hence the two vectors $-\frac34\alpha_1-\frac34\alpha_2+\alpha_4$ and $\alpha_3$ span this subspace. Since they are linearly independent, they form a basis of $W_1\cap W_2,$ which is therefore a plane in $\Bbb R^6$ hence defined by $6-2=4$ equations, which we now look for.

A vector $(x_1,\dots,x_6)$ belongs to this subspace if and only if there exists two real numbers $w,z$ such that
$$\begin{cases}x_1&=\frac12w+z\\x_2&=\frac74w\\x_3&=-\frac94w-z\\x_4&=-z\\x_5&=-\frac34w\\x_6&=\frac34w+z.
\end{cases}$$
Using for instance the 4th and 5th equations to eliminate $w,z,$ we find that $W_1\cap W_2$ is defined by the following 4 equations:
$$\begin{cases}x_1&=-\frac23x_5-x_4\\x_2&=-\frac73x_5\\x_3&=3x_5+x_4\\x_6&=-x_5-x_4.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: As usual, Anne, your answers are as clear as day. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As you have done, you can consider the equation of $W_2$ and then find the intersection with the equation of $W_1$.

$\left.W_2=\begin{cases}
a+b+c+2d=x_1\\
-a+d=x_2\\
a+2b-c=x_3\\
-a+b-c=x_4\\
a=x_5\\
-a+c=x_6
\end{cases}\implies
\begin{cases}
a=x_5\\
b=x_4+2x_5+x_6\\
c=x_5+x_6\\
d=x_2+x_5\\
a+b+c+2d=x_1\\
a+2b-c=x_3
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
x_1=2x_2+x_4+6x_5+2x_6\\
2x_3=2x_4+4x_5+x_6
\end{cases}\right.
$

Now you can find the equation and a base for $W_1\cap W_2$ .